# How can a compact set on R^n be closed (heine borel), when by definition a compact set has to be finitely covered by open sets?

Tags: general-topology, compactness, covering-spaces

A compact set A is defined st given a cover of open sets of A, there exist a finte subcover with elements in that original cover. And so A is defined as a finite union of open sets, and so A should be open (def of a topological space, the intersection of two opens is open itself). By heine borel, in R^n a compact set is closed (and bounded). The question is therefore: is A a closed or an open set?

Comment: $A$ is covered by finitely many opens sets means $A\subset \cup_{i=1}^n U_i$, where $U_i$'s are open. $\{a\}$ is closed and $\{a\}\subset (a-\epsilon,a+\epsilon)$. So it has a finite cover of open sets.

Answer (score 3):

The key word here is “covered”. A set $K$ is compact if, when $K$ is *contained* in an union of open sets, then $K$ is *contained* in the union of finitely many of those sets. It is *not* being claimed that $K$ *is* the union of those sets.

Comment: I imagined that was the important point. I have to notice that the wikipedia page "Cover (Topology)" in english is therefore inprecise, since it defines a cover of A as a family of subsets of A, but we are using the word "cover" with the wikipedia meaning of "subcover"

Comment: @Pinco Pallino: no, it is precise. You have to distinguish between open in $\mathbb {R}^n$ and open in $A$. For instance, $A$ is always open in $A$. So, the *definition* of compactness refers to sets open in $A$, which is an absolute property, i.e., it has nothing to do with any space $A$ might be contained in. It is then a (almost trivial) "theorem" that this is equivalent to the statement given above by José Carlos Santos. Anyway, try to prove it! It will help you to understand the concept.